# Paypal/Alertpat/Google Checkout: Online payment

Tags: paypal, google-checkout

I want to create a application that allows artist to upload their works and sell them. I intend to collect a certain amount as commission but I don't know of any payment tool/method that permits this feature. The process goes like this:  User clicks on checkout, the system pays the artist and I receive my commission.

Does paypal, alertpay, Google checkout allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! **PayPal's Adaptive Payment API** solves this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything like it and I think your idea is great because it would save a lot of time.

Maybe what you can do is set the payment to go your account and then you transfer the money without the commission for the artist.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks. I found out that this can be done with Paypal's Adaptive Payment API.